# Deriving a formula for the lower-bound of rotating a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, prime-numbers, closed-form, rotations

For any prime number $n$, let $x$ be the set [1:n] and let $S$ be a concatenated sequence of $n$ sub-sequences that are constructed by repeating each $(i \in x)$ for $n$ times.

For example when $n=5$ , S=[ 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5].

Now, Suppose we circularly shift $S$ with an integer ($j \in [1:n^2]$ ) such that $j$ is not a multiple of $n$.

I need to derive a formula in terms of $j$ and $n$ that find how many rotation times needed to make $S$ starts with all the $n$ numbers?

For example, consider our $S$ sequence mentioned above for $n=5$ , Suppose the rotation shift is $j=6$.

- Without rotation:

S=[ **1** 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5].

- 1st rotation:  $S1=$ *Rotate*($S,6$),

S1=[**2** 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 1 1 1 1 1 2].

- 2nd rotation:  $S2=$ *Rotate*($S1,6$),

S2=[**3** 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3].

- 3rd rotation:  $S3=$ *Rotate*($S2,6$),

S3=[**4** 4 5 5 5 5 5 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3].

- 4th rotation:  $S4=$ *Rotate*($S3,6$),

S4=[**5** 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3  4 4 5 5 5 5].

As we can see from the example , 4 times of rotations needed to guarantee that $S$ starts with the {2, 3, 4, 5} numbers.

Please be informed that the upper bound can be derived as $lcm(j,n^2)$. However,   this bound is not tight to obtain the exact number of rotations. Therefore, I am looking for a formula that find the lower-bound of rotations which obtain the exact required number of rotations.

Also, Please note that I can find that number of rotations through simulation where the tables below give some examples. However, I could not derive an exact mathematical formula for the lower-bound in terms of $n$ and $j$. So, I need an urgent help on that please.

1)  When $n=3$
$$\begin{array}{c|c|} 
  \text{the shift amount } (j) & \text{Number of rotations} \\ \hline
 4,  7 & 2 \\ \hline
 2, 5 & 3 \\ \hline
 8 & 4 \\ \hline
 1 & 6 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

2)  When $n=5$
$$\begin{array}{c|c|} 
  \text{the shift amount } (j) & \text{Number of rotations} \\ \hline
 6,  11, 16, 21 & 4 \\ \hline
 4,  9, 14, 19 & 5 \\ \hline
 7, 18, 22 & 6 \\ \hline
 3 & 7 \\ \hline
 8, 23 & 8 \\ \hline
 2, 17 & 10 \\ \hline
 12 & 12 \\ \hline
 13 & 15 \\ \hline
 24 & 16 \\ \hline
 1 & 20 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you missed something in the bound I gave before. hint: remainder math and quotients.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee What did I miss. You are welcome to clarify your idea here.

Comment: it wasn't just lcm(j,n^2) , the quotient remainder part I'm talking about is we know for example that certain values skip at some point. that increases their value.

Comment: Could you give examples from the table above to illustrate please because I really can`t get your idea ??

Comment: for 8 in n=3 the reason it's 4 is because once you hit the 9th element  8=2*3+2 so it will skip 2 which then lands it in the third set of numbers again. and then after that because the 8th position is less than 2 away from the 9th place it will land in the third set of numbers again and now because 7 is 2 less than 9 it will land in the second set of numbers the one that wasn't touched before.

Comment: Ok, that`s correct. Now how can we express these skipping  in a formula that is valid for any values of n and j ?

Comment: it relates to modular arithmetic ( remainder math/clock math) and division  in the above  8 is dividend, first 2 the quotient, 3 the divisor, and the other 2 that's being added is the remainder.  j is the dividend, n is the divisors, the rest are determined by those two.

Comment: For example When $n=5$
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|} 
  \text{the shift amount } (j) & \text{Quotient} & \text{Reminder}& \text{Number of rotations} \\ \hline
 6,  11, 16, 21 & 1,2,3,4& 1&  4 \\ \hline
 4,  9, 14, 19 & 0, 1,2,3& 4 & 5 \\ \hline
 7, 22 & 1,4& 2& 6 \\ \hline
   18 & 3& 3& 6 \\ \hline
3 & 0& 3& 7 \\ \hline
 8, 23 & 1,4 & 3& 8 \\ \hline
 2, 17 & 0,3 & 2& 10 \\ \hline
 12 & 2& 2& 12 \\ \hline
 13 & 2& 3& 15 \\ \hline
 24 & 4& 4& 16 \\ \hline
 1 & 0& 1& 20 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: Through testing some $n$ examples, I found that the pair of (quotient and remainder) is different for every $j$ . above is an example for n=5 . However I failed to find a relation between these parameters and the lower-bound. Can any body help regarding that please